# In angular 9 is it possible to share data across routed components that is build as chrome extension?

Tags: angular, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, angular-material

I have two angular 9 components and once service. The service has providedIn: 'root'. Component A loads a private property in the service, When I try to use the property from the service in component B, it is empty. Both the components are in same module. Do I need to put the service in 'providers' in module? I'm building the angular app into a chrome extension and component B is the background component stated through a route.

Comment: The background script runs in a separate hidden background page so maybe your architecture doesn't account for that.

Comment: yes, I think that could be the problem